# Batch size for custom Collate Function with variable input sizes

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, pytorch-dataloader

I am writing a multi-class image classification and distance estimation network. The dataset I am using consists of images and their corresponding annotation file (containing class id, bbox, distance) as shown below.

```
1,74,127,92,139,47
```

I have written custom dataloader for this task as presented below.

```py
class CreateDataLoader(Dataset):
    #constructor
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transforms=None):
        
        self.root       = root_dir    
        self.csvs       = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, "csv")))) #Get list of all csv files
        self.images     = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, "images"))))#Get list of all images 
        
        self.transforms  = transforms

    def __getitem__(self, index):
    
        # acquire image, label, its bounding box coordinates and the distance to object
        imagePath = os.path.join(self.root, "images", self.images[index])
        
        filename, ext =  os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(imagePath))
        csvFilename = filename.replace('camera', 'CSV')
        csvFile = os.path.join(self.root, "csv", (csvFilename + ".csv"))
        
        image = Image.open(imagePath).convert("RGB")
        
        bboxes = []
        objectLabels = []
        distances = []
        
        
        with open(csvFile, 'r') as read_obj:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(read_obj)
            for row in csv_reader:
                objectLabel = row[0]
                Xmin        = np.array(row[1])
                Ymin        = np.array(row[2])
                Xmax        = np.array(row[3])
                Ymax        = np.array(row[4])
                distance    = np.array(row[5])
                
                bbox = np.array([Xmin, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax], dtype=int)
                
                bboxes.append(bbox)
                objectLabels.append(int(objectLabel))
                distances.append(distance)
                
                
        distances = np.array(distances, dtype=float)
        objectLabels = np.array(objectLabels, dtype=float)
        
        #make everything to torch tensor, important question is it required for bounding boxes??
        bboxes = torch.as_tensor(bboxes, dtype=torch.float32)
        objectLabels = torch.as_tensor(objectLabels, dtype=torch.float32)
        distances = torch.as_tensor(distances, dtype=torch.float32)
        
        if self.transforms is not None:
            image = self.transforms(image)

        return image, objectLabels, bboxes, distances

    def __len__(self):
        # return the size of the dataset
        return len(self.images)
```

Since, the length of objectLabels, bboxes and distances vary with image (due to objects present in the image), I had to write a custom collate function as below.

```py
def collate_fn_Custom( batch):

    images = list()
    boxes = list()
    objectLabels = list()
    distances = list()

    for b in batch:
        images.append(b[0])
        objectLabels.append(b[1])
        boxes.append(b[2])
        
        distances.append(b[3])

    images = torch.stack(images, dim=0)

    return images, objectLabels, boxes, distances
```

It works fine for batch size of 1. But I am failing to understand how I can extend it for larger batch sizes. Of course, I can pass any batch size as an argument, but how can the model differentiate among different different images and their corresponding annotation for multiple batch size.
The source for collate function is [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1512).

Comment: maybe the [pad_sequence](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence.html) function can help you in this case.